# Proggram get stuck when using Barrier Python

Tags: python, multithreading, barrier

I need synchronize my thread to execute them concurrently this is all working without the barrier but the threads execute on avg. 2 per second and i need at least 50-100 threads executing at the same time.

When i use Barrier in my code my program gets stuck like a Dead Lock.

```
def Spin_Clients(self):
    def get_clients():
        self.connect_to_database1()
        self.get_message_from_client1()
    client_list = []
    barrier = Barrier(10)
    def send_messages():
        global MessageNumber
        global machineName
        global staffName
        timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
        logging.info("Thread {} working on something".format(threading.current_thread()))

        logging.info("Thread {} working on something1".format(threading.current_thread()))

        machineName = final_result[MessageNumber][0]
        logging.info("Thread {} working on something2".format(threading.current_thread()))

        staffName = staff_results[MessageNumber][0]
        logging.info("Thread {} working on something3".format(threading.current_thread()))
        MessageNumber += 1
        logging.info("Thread {} working on something4".format(threading.current_thread()))

        r = requests.post(
            "http://sampleurl"+ staffName + "&locationId=" + machineName)
        logging.info("Thread {} working on something5".format(threading.current_thread()))

        barrier.wait(timeout=5)
        logging.info("Response Code Should be 202: " + str(r.status_code) + " Time: " + timestamp)

        logging.info("Thread {} working on something6".format(threading.current_thread()))

    for i in range(10):
        t = Thread(target=send_messages(), args=(i,))
        t.start()
        logging.info("Message Sent to: " + staffName + " " + machineName)
    for thread in client_list:
        thread.join()
```

I need to send 50-100 post request per second how can achieve this using python thread synchronization?

I don't get any error i need to kill the session to close my problem when its running.

As per Comment after adding a timeout and logging every line this is what i get as results

```
INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something    
09:19:53.929    INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something1   
09:19:53.929    INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something2   
09:19:53.929    INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something3   
09:19:53.929    INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something4   
09:19:53.963    INFO    Thread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 68480)> working on something5   
09:19:58.964    FAIL    BrokenBarrierError
```

UPDATE 2:

Now i am just trying to run a simple print thread but I am still getting `BrokenBarrierError`

```
def Spin_Clients(self, NumMessages):


    def get_clients():
        self.connect_to_database1()
        self.get_message_from_client1()
    client_list = []
    barrier = Barrier(10)

    def send_messages():

        logging.info("Thread {} Working on something".format(threading.current_thread()))
        logging.info("Thread {} I have Reached the barrier".format(threading.current_thread()))
        barrier.wait(timeout=10)
    for i in range(10):
        client_list.append(Thread(target=send_messages(), args=(i,)))
        client_list[].start()

    for thread in client_list:
        thread.join()
    print("All threads have finished")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, why do you have a `barrier.wait()` only just before the last line? That will just wait until all threads get to that line and then let them end, it doesn't really synchronize them. Also, why do you have a `sleep(2)`? Lastly, you're modifying global variables inside concurrent threads, I think you should reconsider that.

Comment: @ChatterOne What i am trying to achieve is to wait until all threads send request and then release them at the same time, I have barrier.wait() before the last line because from my understanding of barrier is that they will send the request and then get blocked and it will wait until the last threads send the request then it should release them

Comment: If one of your threads dies or quits before calling `barrier.wait()`, it will wait indefinitely (because you didn't specify a timeout). This is likely to happen especially because, as I said, you're modifying global variable in concurrent threads without a lock system, so there's a chance of messing up. put log lines just before... well, every line, and see if it stops somewhere. Do not use a debugger, that will probably not help you because of the multiple threads.

Comment: Also I have comment out all the global variables and i just tried a simple printing thread, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: If you have a `BrokenBarrierError` then you're destroying the barrier somehow. I see that you have a loop on `client_list` to join the threads but where is client_list filled? Is it possible that it's empty and you don't wait for any thread?

Comment: You are passing the result of `send_messages` as target for the child-threads instead of just the function `send_message`. Should be: `Thread(target=send_messages, args=(i,))`.

Comment: @ChatterOne i have update my question once again

Comment: @Darkonaut is right, I didn't spot that.